# Interfacing Indoor Positioning Android Mobile App with Google Maps / Indoor Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, indoor-positioning-system, google-indoor-maps

I am a student and am attempting to create an indoor positioning system for my department. I'm using a WiFi-based localization system utilizing the existing APs. Right now I'm researching different maps to use for my project.

Can Google Maps be used for a custom image (like a floor plan)? Or can a mobile application be interfaced with the existing Google Maps API? If so could you please link to references?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure about indoor positioning, but I used Google Maps API for you know.. maps. Below is the link for the Google Maps APIs.

https://developers.google.com/maps/

My classmate did a project quite similar to yours. He drew the indoor layout (floor plan) himself and set it in his Android Application.

After reading this link: https://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/
It seems Google has made an API.

Found it, here you go:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#indoor_maps